# CSS different for homepage and other pages opencart

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, opencart

I'm working on a mobile version of our website with Media Queries, but I'm facing some strange problems with the CSS.

I've made the homepage fully responsive on a mobile device (< 480px) and it looks good to me:
[image: home page who is working fine]

Now i'm working on the second page (tuinontwerp)
This page uses the same blocks as the homepage, but the css is different:

[image: tuinontwerp page with different css]

As you can see, the brown blocks are wider, but the css is the same. Even in the Chrome dev tools inspector, it's exactly the same.

Here's my css for the blocks:

```
#diensten-row {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
    height: 120px;
}

#diensten-row a{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#diensten {
    background-color: #996633;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 8px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

HTML: (still looking for the file that contains the divs)

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you also post the HTML? Since i see you only use ID's in your CSS you've showed so far, I guess it might have something to do with using ID's more than once. But as I can't check your HTML it's just a guess :)

Comment: I've added the html, but I'm not sure where to find that, I've copied it from the page source in chrome.

Comment: @superDiglett forget to tag you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the widths of `#diensten-row`, `#diensten` and `#diensten-row a` are 100%, I predict the container width of the `tuinontwerp` page is slighty bigger than on the first page.

Also a tip: Don't use `ID's` more than once. I see you use the ID `#diensten` multiple times. Use a class for that. An `ID` should only be used when a elementen is only used once. But even then I preffer using `classes`.

Comment: Problem is that this isn't my website, I did not code it, so it's hard for me to find the files in opencart. As far as I can see there's only one page, with the class container.  This container is set to 480px in my mobile.css, and to 960px in my stylesheet.css

Comment: As you can see, the logo and cart/menu are within the 480px range, but the categories (tuinontwerp, tuinaanleg and doe het zelf) aren't. Even when the container is set to 480px. I don't see things that could change that.

Comment: Do you have a live example of this? Then I can inspect it myself. This was the only `logical` reason for the issue :)

Comment: I can't find the file where #diensten and #diensten-row are located.